# What work is titled "Distresses of the Industrious Population"?

Tags: identification-request, historical-context

From George W. M. Reynolds' [*The Mysteries of London*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysteries_of_London) (1844–1845):

> "Ah!" said the bookseller, after a pause; "nothing now succeeds unless
>   it's in the comic line. We have comic Latin grammars, and comic Greek
>   grammars; indeed, I don't know but what English grammar, too, is a comedy altogether.
>   All our tragedies are made into comedies by the way they are performed;
>   and no work sells without comic illustrations to it. I have brought out
>   several new comic works, which have been very successful. For instance,
>   'The Comic [*Wealth of Nations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wealth_of_Nations)';
>   'The Comic *Parliamentary Speeches*';
>   'The Comic [*Report of the Poor-Law Commissioners*](https://books.google.com/books?id=2FnbAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover),'
>   with an Appendix containing the 'Comic [Dietary Scale](https://books.google.com/books?id=2FnbAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA64)';
>   and the 'Comic *Distresses of the Industrious Population*.' I even propose to bring out a
>   'Comic [*Whole Duty of Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Whole_Duty_of_Man).'
>   All these books sell well: they do admirably
>   for the nurseries of the children of the aristocracy. In fact they are
>   as good as manuals and text-books."

I can identify most of the references here, but I don't know exactly what is meant by "Distresses of the Industrious Population." I know that the "industrious population" is what we would today call the "working poor," and that the [Poor-Law Commission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poor_Law_Commission) was charged with ameliorating their "distresses"; but was there a specific work of literature, or report, or famous speech, that would have been immediately understood by Reynolds' use of the title "*Distresses of the Industrious Population*"?

Comment: It may relate to this parliamentary debate of 1827. https://api.parliament.uk/historic-hansard/commons/1827/jun/14/distress-of-the-commercial-and

Answer (score 5, accepted):

John Thelwall was an 18th century British parliamentary and social reformer. He worked primarily as a journalist and editor, but was also a teacher of rhetoric and elocution. He was involved in some of the earliest modern speech therapy interventions.

He delivered a lecture titled *The Distresses of the Industrious Population* in March of 1795. You can find the text [here](https://oll.libertyfund.org/title/thelwall-the-tribune#lf1651_head_004).

Although Thelwall is probably not well-known outside of the United Kingdom, searching [Google scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22John%20Thelwall%22&btnG=) reveals thousands of books and articles which mention him. He may be well-known enough to mention alongside the other works and for Reynold's readers to understand what is meant.

There are other possibilities. In a comment, Spagirl mentioned a parliamentary debate with a [somewhat similar title](https://api.parliament.uk/historic-hansard/commons/1827/jun/14/distress-of-the-commercial-and). Friedrich Engels published *The Condition of the Working Class of England* in 1844 (the same year *Mysteries of London* was published). However, the other works in the quote are all direct titles. It seems unusual that only this one title would be paraphrased, so I think Thelwall is the most likely choice.